# jQuery ajax problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I don't have any expirience in ajax functions of jQuery. I'm trying to make simple call like:

```
$.get ("ajaxsupport/login");
```

I have a servlet with url-pattern ("ajaxsupport/login").

When I type in browser's address field "http://localhost:9090/ajaxsupport/login" I see some result. But $.get (..) doesn't even make a call.

What is the problem?

I use jquery 1.3.1

Comment: do you see any exceptions? can you past the whole code of using $.get?

Comment: That string is the whole code. None exception occurs.

Answer (score 5):

`$.get` is an *asynchronous* method call by default, meaning the caller remains in control. That's why
something must happen, when the request has been executed. You specify that by defining a callback.

```
jQuery.get( url, [data], [callback], [type] )
```

In your case (note the prepended '/', it may not be necessary, depending on the scripts location, though):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.get("/ajaxsupport/login", 
        function(data, textStatus){ 
            // just prompt the response and the status message
            alert(data + "\n" + textStatus); 
        } 
    );

});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried with and without lead slash. Function is not beeing executed ever. There is no call to servlet, I don't know why.

Comment: maybe you can edit your question to include some more code (e.g. the  $(document).ready ... enclosing and the imports)?

Answer (score 1):

Try to find out if you get a result:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax
 ({
    type: "GET",
    url:"/ajaxsupport/login",
    success: function(result)
    {
        alert("I'm a success");
    }
});
```

});

You can also use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to what is requested and returned.

Answer (score 0):

Get a tool like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  Watch at how the request goes over the wire.  Is it going to where you think it's going?  Are you getting a response?  Can you put a breakpoint on your web service call?

Answer (score 0):

**Two Variable asynchronous sending to server [Raw JavaScript || Jquery ]] **

```js
var demo = document.querySelector('#demo');
var x = 0;
var y = 0;


//pure
demo.innerHTML = x;
demo.addEventListener('click',()=> {
    x=5;
    demo.innerHTML = x;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhttp.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", 'http://localhost/target/index.php', true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send('data='+[x,y]);
});

//framework
$('#demo2').html(y);
$('#demo2').click(()=>{
    y=5;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost/target/index.php',
        data: {
            'y': y,
            'x' : x
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        #demo,#demo2{
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: #f12100;
        }
        #demo2{
            background-color: #20c997;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="demo"></div>
<br>
<div id="demo2"></div>
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to the 10 year old question that the questioner agreed was  a type.

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks